# Reshape2 - multiple rows to single rows with name change and varying numbers of rows per group

Tags: r, plyr, reshape, reshape2

I have the following data set but am a newbie to the reshape2 functions:

```
df<-data.frame(Site=c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C"),
               PolygonArea=c(0.6, 0.3, 0.1, 0.7, 0.3, 1.0),
               OriginYear=c(1900, 1910, 1905, 1950, 1975, 2000))
```

I want to turn `df`into a dataframe with this structure:

```
df2<-data.frame(Site=c("A", "B", "C"),
               PolygonArea1=c(0.6,0.7,1.0),
               OriginYear1=c(1900, 1950,2000),
               PolygonArea2 = c(0.3, 0.3, NA),
               OriginYear2 = c(1910, 1975, NA),
               PolygonArea3 = c(0.1, NA, NA),
               OriginYear3 = c(1905, NA, NA))
```

I've tried without success to use the reshape2 package as my example has 'NA' cells as well as no aggregate function. Also, the column headers change names (i.e., the '1', '2', '3', etc.).

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
df2 <- dcast(
    melt(cbind(df, ID=ave(rep.int(1, nrow(df)), df$Site, FUN=seq_along)),   
    id.vars=c("Site","ID")), Site~variable+ID
)
```

Here we use `ave` to give each row a unique ID for each site. So just looking at that part, that gives

```
#cbind(df, ID=ave(rep.int(1, nrow(df)), df$Site, FUN=seq_along))
  Site PolygonArea OriginYear ID
1    A         0.6       1900  1
2    A         0.3       1910  2
3    A         0.1       1905  3
4    B         0.7       1950  1
5    B         0.3       1975  2
6    C         1.0       2000  1
```

Then we melt the variables along Site/ID. This looks like

```
#head(melt(cbind(df, ID=ave(rep.int(1, nrow(df)), df$Site, FUN=seq_along)), id.vars=c("Site","ID")))
  Site ID    variable value
1    A  1 PolygonArea   0.6
2    A  2 PolygonArea   0.3
3    A  3 PolygonArea   0.1
4    B  1 PolygonArea   0.7
5    B  2 PolygonArea   0.3
6    C  1 PolygonArea   1.0
```

Then we dcast them to get them in the order you want.

```
  Site PolygonArea_1 PolygonArea_2 PolygonArea_3 OriginYear_1 OriginYear_2 OriginYear_3
1    A           0.6           0.3           0.1         1900         1910         1905
2    B           0.7           0.3            NA         1950         1975           NA
3    C           1.0            NA            NA         2000           NA           NA
```

This does put a "_" in the variable names. But if you want to remove it, you can do

```
names(df2) <- gsub("_(?=[^_]+$)","", names(df2), perl=T)
```

(it's a bit awkward but i want to make sure to remove only the last "_" and not any others)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution via `tidyr` and `dplyr`.  Because you build the new column names manually, you can specify that they should not include underscores:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(Site) %>%
  mutate(id = seq_along(PolygonArea)) %>%
  gather(resp,value,PolygonArea:OriginYear) %>% 
  mutate(resp = paste0(resp,id)) %>%
  select(-id) %>%
  spread(resp,value) %>%
  select(ends_with("1"),ends_with("2"),ends_with("3"))

  OriginYear1 PolygonArea1 OriginYear2 PolygonArea2 OriginYear3 PolygonArea3
1        1900          0.6        1910          0.3        1905          0.1
2        1950          0.7        1975          0.3          NA           NA
3        2000          1.0          NA           NA          NA           NA
```